# CSS multiple pseudo classes and pseudo elements

Tags: css, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

Is this CSS syntax exist and safe to use for all modern browsers.

```
footer ul.footer-menu li:not(:first-child):after
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it works, see the snippet below.

```css
footer ul.footer-menu li:not(:first-child):after {
    content: 'added some text';
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <ul class="footer-menu">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut tempora voluptatum praesentium rem culpa, cupiditate quas animi commodi voluptates? Cupiditate error cum suscipit dolorum deleniti? Non dolore, cumque assumenda voluptatum.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut tempora voluptatum praesentium rem culpa, cupiditate quas animi commodi voluptates? Cupiditate error cum suscipit dolorum deleniti? Non dolore, cumque assumenda voluptatum.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut tempora voluptatum praesentium rem culpa, cupiditate quas animi commodi voluptates? Cupiditate error cum suscipit dolorum deleniti? Non dolore, cumque assumenda voluptatum.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut tempora voluptatum praesentium rem culpa, cupiditate quas animi commodi voluptates? Cupiditate error cum suscipit dolorum deleniti? Non dolore, cumque assumenda voluptatum.</li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

And yes it is safe to use on all modern browsers. According to caniuse.com, the support is close to 98% around the world for [generated content by pseudo-elements](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent) (`:after`), for [CSS 2.1 selectors](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2) (`:first-child`) and [CSS 3 selectors](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) (`:not`).

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

`:not` **97.72%** Global Browser support

`:first-child`  **97.74%** Global Browser support

`:after` **97.72%** Global Browser support

> #### You can always find out if you can use ... here
>
> #### REF: https://caniuse.com/

Comment: What, EXACTLY, does global browser support mean? All versions of all browsers? All versions of all browsers in common use? If so, what is the definition of common use and how are the statistics obtained? There seems no way to contact the caniuse website maintainers.